# edit year of date column in a data table with :=

Tags: r, data.table

Is there any way to edit just the year of the date column in a data.table in place?

Something like:

```
dt = data.table(date = seq.Date(today() - 5, today(), 'day'))
dt[, year(date) := 2021]
```

The above does not run with the error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.default(x) :
> do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXlt”

Answer (score 2):

You can use `format` to get date and month information and append year value as 2021.

```
library(data.table)
dt[, date := as.Date(format(date, '2021-%m-%d'))]
dt

#         date
#1: 2021-10-12
#2: 2021-10-13
#3: 2021-10-14
#4: 2021-10-15
#5: 2021-10-16
#6: 2021-10-17
```

Answer (score 1):

The following seems far fetched but it works.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt[, date := lapply(.SD, function(x) {year(x) <- 2021; x})]

dt
#         date
#1: 2021-10-11
#2: 2021-10-12
#3: 2021-10-13
#4: 2021-10-14
#5: 2021-10-15
#6: 2021-10-16
```

Comment: `year(dt$date) <- 2021`